# composer into existing project using vendor-dir

Tags: php, composer-php, packagist

I have following situation, i am starting with composer BUT...

I have following dir structure, following is my include folder specified in php.ini

```
d:\Inetpub\include\
```

I have a autoload.php under this folder following PRS-0

I create new objects like this.

```
$test = new \ownFrame\Base\Document\Pdf();
```

The folder for above is, sow the autoloader works fine

```
d:\Inetpub\include\ownFrame\Base\Document\Pdf.php
```

In my pdf class i make use an outdated version of tcpdf, Tcpdf is located under

```
d:\Inetpub\include\ownFrame\Plugins\Pdf\tcpdf.php
```

Sow here we go. I want to start using Composer, i have downloaded it under the include folder. I will remove the old version, that was on the old way by extracting zip and copy it to folder.

if i require tcpdf it will standard be placed under if i use Composer

```
d:\Inetpub\include\vendor\tecnick.com\tcpdf
```

BUT: i want that tcpdf is under

```
d:\Inetpub\include\ownFrame\Plugins\tcpdf
```

I have he folowing but it does not work.

```
{
    "name": "ownFrame/Base",
    "description": "ownFrame framework",
    "version": "v24.0.0",
    "type": "library",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Jan Van Looveren",
            "email": "",
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
        },
        "files": [
            "optiload.php"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "ownFrame/Plugins/tcpdf/"
    },
    "require": {
        "tecnick.com/tcpdf": ">=6.*"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need TCPDF to be located anywhere special! All you have to do is include the generated file `vendor/autoload.php` whenever you intend to use a class that is fetched with Composer.

So you can simply include the autoloader every time (preferably in a central script that is loaded at the beginning), and then just use the classes. You do not need to worry where they are located. They are loaded whenever they are needed.

Comment: Can, but i tcpdf is not the only package i want to start managing via composer, sow all the other packages have to go under plugins as well, this is to keep the structure clean

Comment: Do not worry about the structure. The contents of the `vendor` folder are none of your business. The published API to make use of them is to include the autoload.php and then use the classes that every package offers. Just think what would happen if Composer decides to rearrange the files completely. Or if any package decides to do that. If you rely on the structure of that folder, you introduce a dependency that shouldn't be there. `vendor` says only one thing: This is external code that is supposed to work, but not part of the project otherwise.